# MongoDB Filter child array take 3 conditional

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AHeA4eTdNin)

I have a collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "ProjectId": 123,
    "FeedbackClient": [
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-01", "Grade": 2, "DateVoted": "2021-01-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-02", "Grade": 5, "DateVoted": "2021-02-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-03", "Grade": 2, "DateVoted": "2021-03-05" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-04", "Grade": 5, "DateVoted": "2021-04-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-05", "Grade": null, "DateVoted": null },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-06", "Grade": null, "DateVoted": null }
    ],
    "FeedbackFinal": { "Grade": 4, "DateVoted": "2021-01-01" }
  },
  {
    "ProjectId": 456,
    "FeedbackClient": [
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-01", "Grade": 2, "DateVoted": "2021-01-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-02", "Grade": 2, "DateVoted": "2021-02-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-03", "Grade": 5, "DateVoted": "2021-03-05" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-04", "Grade": 1, "DateVoted": "2021-04-01" },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-05", "Grade": null, "DateVoted": null },
      { "SentOn": "2021-01-06", "Grade": null, "DateVoted": null }
    ],
    "FeedbackFinal": null
  }
]
```

I need to implement this simple logic:

1. If "FeedbackFinal" is not null, grab it's Grade
2. If "FeedbackFinal" is null, I need the "FeedbackClient" AVG of last 3 voted grades (DateVoted not null and sort DESC)

I could get closer doing a AGGERGATION & PROJECT like this:

```
{
    Grade: { $cond: { if: { $ne: [ "$FeedbackFinal", null ] }, 
                        then: "$FeedbackFinal.Grade", 
                        else: { $avg: "$FeedbackClient.Grade"} } }
}
```

But here I am doing the AVG of all and not just the last 3 DESC by DateVoted

What is the correct way to do this? MAP & FILTER and then AVG? PUSH only the DAteVoted NOT null to another prop and then AVG on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1:

```js
db.feedbacks.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$FeedbackClient" },
    {
        $sort: {
            "FeedbackClient.DateVoted": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            ProjectId: { $first: "$ProjectId" },
            FeedbackClient: { $push: "$FeedbackClient" },
            FeedbackFinal: { $first: "$FeedbackFinal" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            grade: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $ifNull: ["$FeedbackFinal", true] },
                    then: { $avg: { $slice: ["$FeedbackClient.Grade", 3] } },
                    else: "$FeedbackFinal.Grade"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Solution #2: If using MongoDB version 4.4+

```js
db.feedbacks.aggregate([
    {
        $set: {
            fbcForAvg: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(FeedbackClient) {
                        FeedbackClient.sort((a, b) => {
                          return new Date(b.DateVoted).getTime() - new Date(a.DateVoted).getTime()
                        });
                        
                        return FeedbackClient.slice(0, 3);
                    },
                    args: ["$FeedbackClient"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            grade: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $ifNull: ["$FeedbackFinal", true] },
                    then: { $avg: "$fbcForAvg.Grade" },
                    else: "$FeedbackFinal.Grade"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { "fbcForAvg": 0 }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/8/2021, 5:15:51 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60460e6fa4a6a12690d3fd8a"),
    "ProjectId" : 123,
    "FeedbackClient" : [
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-04",
            "Grade" : 5,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-04-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-03",
            "Grade" : 2,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-03-05"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-02",
            "Grade" : 5,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-02-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-01",
            "Grade" : 2,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-01-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-05",
            "Grade" : null,
            "DateVoted" : null
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-06",
            "Grade" : null,
            "DateVoted" : null
        }
    ],
    "FeedbackFinal" : {
        "Grade" : 4,
        "DateVoted" : "2021-01-01"
    },
    "grade" : 4
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/8/2021, 5:15:51 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60460e6fa4a6a12690d3fd8b"),
    "ProjectId" : 456,
    "FeedbackClient" : [
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-04",
            "Grade" : 1,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-04-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-03",
            "Grade" : 5,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-03-05"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-02",
            "Grade" : 2,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-02-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-01",
            "Grade" : 2,
            "DateVoted" : "2021-01-01"
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-05",
            "Grade" : null,
            "DateVoted" : null
        },
        {
            "SentOn" : "2021-01-06",
            "Grade" : null,
            "DateVoted" : null
        }
    ],
    "FeedbackFinal" : null,
    "grade" : 2.6666666666666665
}
```

Comment: Here in the example I added just ProjectId, but in real life I have like 30 props.... is there a way to project them without having to do the grouping one by one calling $first? 2nd problem... I have FeedbackClient and FeedbackPartner... I have to do Unwind, sort, group for client and then another for partner or could be done together at once?

Comment: Then use the Solution #2, if u have MongoDB version >= 4.4

Comment: unfortunately I don't... 3.4... I will replicate the logic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `FeedbackClient` and filter elements that `DateVoted` is not null
- `$slice` to slice last 3 elements from above filtered elements
- `$let` to declare a variable called `client` and above actions result will be in `client`, in to get average of above `client`'s filtered array of `Grade`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "ProjectId": 5.0,
      Grade: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: ["$FeedbackFinal", null] },
          then: "$FeedbackFinal.Grade",
          else: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                client: {
                  $slice: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$FeedbackClient",
                        cond: { $ne: ["$$this.DateVoted", null] }
                      }
                    },
                    -3
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: { $avg: "$$client.Grade" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rNGcu2HBtY_)

Comment: Here work partial, missing the sort part in DateVoted. thanks anyway.

Comment: if your every push has latest date entry then no need to sort just grab last 3 elements.

Comment: answer by Dheemanth Bhat is good but it will sort by string not by date, in some cases it will fail. it will work if you convert it to date type and than sort.